# How do I make Sharepoint 2013 Ribbon cookies secure

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How do I make Sharepoint 2013 Ribbon cookies(Ribbon.WikiPageTab and Ribbon.Read) secure?

Comment: what do you mean "secure" ?

Comment: I want it to be http and secure only cookie

Comment: can you provide example ? I still do not understand what do you mean "http and secure only"

Comment: When Ribbon.Read is created, I want it to be "http only" and "secure" for security scan purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a call with Microsoft support about it.. came to know these cookies are created by JavaScript at the client end. If we mark those Secure or HttpOnly, functionality for which these are created will be lost.

Technically we can still mark these cookies HttpOnly and Secure by updating code in JavaScript function named “storeDataCooki” in CUI.js (under the _layouts/15 virtual path)